# Is there a way to use EJS variables in HTML inputs?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am trying use a check box to send all selected users to a new page and am wondering how this could be done (using mongodb to store information) My existing code is as follows,

first I render the page

```
router.get("/admin", ensureAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
    User.find()
    .then(user => {
        res.render("admin", {
            user: user,
        });

    })
});
```

For all of the users the website has I create a check box, and all selected users should get sent to a new page

```
<% for (i in user) { %>
        <form action="/admin" method="POST">
            <label for="checkbox"><%=user[i].name%></label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="user" name="user">
        </form>
    <% } %>
    <button type="submit">View Profile</button>
```

however when I console log it says that user info is undefined.

```
router.post("/admin", (req, res) => {
    profile = req.body.name
    console.log(`user info: ${profile}`)
    res.redirect("/admin/userprofile")

    router.get("/admin/userProfile", ensureAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
       
        res.render("admin_user_profile", {
            user: profile
        })
    });
})
```

any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your page contains one `<form>` element *per user* but only *one* submit button overall. Either include the submit button in the `<form>`, but then you can only submit one of the users. Or move the `<form>` and `</form>` outside the `for` loop (and `</form>` after the submit button) and give every `<input>` a unique name, for example,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="<%=user[i].name%>" name="<%=user[i].name%>">
```

Then you can submit all checkboxes at once.

Next, your server-side code refers to `req.body.name`, where should that come from? `req.body` should contain one entry per user name, with the names of your `<input>` elements. And `req.body.firstusername === "on"` if the corresponding checkbox was selected.

In other words, you should get an object like

```js
req.body = {
  "firstusername": "on",
  "thirdusername": "on"
}
```

if the first and third usernames are selected and the second is not selected.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice, I changed the <form> outside of the for loop like you suggested, however when I console.log it on the server side I get [object object] and not the user information itself. any ideas why that is?

Comment: `req.body` *is* an object, see my extended answer.